AttributeError: module 'database.db' has no attribute 'Model'
app.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_cors import CORS
import secrets

from api.user_controller import user_bp

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///development.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secrets.token_hex(16)

    from database import db
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    CORS(app)

    app.register_blueprint(user_bp)

    jwt = JWTManager(app)

    @jwt.expired_token_loader
    def expired_token_callback():
        return jsonify({
            'error': 'Token has expired',
            'message': 'Please refresh your token and try again'
        }), 401

    @jwt.invalid_token_loader
    def invalid_token_callback(error):
        return jsonify({
            'error': 'Invalid token',
            'message': 'Signature verification failed'
        }), 401

    @jwt.unauthorized_loader
    def unauthorized_callback(error):
        return jsonify({
            'error': 'Unauthorized',
            'message': 'Missing Authorization header'
        }), 401

    @jwt.needs_fresh_token_loader
    def token_not_fresh_callback():
        return jsonify({
            'error': 'Fresh token required',
            'message': 'Token is not fresh. Please authenticate again.'
        }), 401

    @jwt.revoked_token_loader
    def revoked_token_callback():
        return jsonify({
            'error': 'Revoked token',
            'message': 'The token has been revoked'
        }), 401

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()

db.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db=SQLAlchemy()


problem is i have encountered with:
AttributeError: module 'database.db' has no attribute 'Model'
when i run my flask app.
db.py is inside of database modul. i have designed for preventing circular import problem which i had encountered before when try to run app.py. but now et an error of attribute.py

do you have any other files? my guess is in your models.py you have something like class X(db.model) without importing db
